# How to get the node name in a webLogic server from Java

Tags: java, weblogic

In a java EE application we have now on jobss, we have the code:
System.getProperty("jboss.host.name");
System.getProperty("jboss.node.name");

to pull the host name and node name.

If I were to do the same in a weblogic server how to do that?

Comment: System.getProperty("weblogic.Name");

Comment: How to get the node?

Comment: JineshEP has answered your question. What more do you need ?

Comment: weblogic.Name is not the node name. It's the server name. So yes I have received partial answer.

Comment: What you call the node name is the hostname ?